# ListView stop column 0 swapping

Tags: winapi, listview, user32

In a standard Microsoft ListView with column swapping enabled how do I go about preventing column 0 being moved or replaced by another column?

Comment: You probably have to sub-class it so you can intercept the HDN_BEGINDRAG notification that the header control generates.

Comment: thank you, I'm looking through these header messages but its not immediately apparent what one deals with the process of dragging so it could be stopped should the column being dragged encroach column 0, would you know?

Comment: @HansPassant: The listview forwards header notifications to its parent, no subclassing is needed.

Comment: @Col_Blimp: There's no notification sent when two items are exchanged during drag & drop, so there's no way to prevent item 0 from moving. The only option I know of is to return TRUE to HDN_BEGINDRAG to block the control's implementation, and handle it yourself by tracking the mouse movements and re-ordering the control manually. The HDM_SETHOTDIVIDER message can provide the same visual feedback as the default behavior.